# Comparing salaries of people doing the same job

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, modeling, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

**How do you compare salaries of two groups (male and female) of workers doing the same job, in order to see if there is a statistically significant difference between their pay?**

I've been reading around about this a lot, but lots of the information out there only looks at very broad groups ie across a whole company or economy.

But what if you are interested in looking for a difference between male and female workers who are doing the same job (or have jobs placed within the same grade ie within the same smaller range of pay)? Any statistical difference could then be used to raise inferences of potential discrimination, but only is significant.

EDIT: the data that I have relate to a large group of employees. They are all on grade 7. This grade includes lots of different sorts of jobs, but for these purposes difference in jobs is irrelevant. Within this pay grade, there are different pay scales, so people are paid according to a range ie pay point 1-5. Where someone is placed within the pay point is determined by length of service but also human decision making. Jobs that have been graded the same should be paid the same, so my aim is to see if there is any difference between the average grade 7 man and average grade 7 woman. If there is, discrimination could be inferred.

My starting point for a test of these two groups was ANOVA, but the normality assumption might not apply to salary data. (It might, but might not; at the broad level, salary data is often lognormal, but that might not be the case at this closer level). You also need groups to be the same size (or at least, close to the same size as the test's power is lost when sizes become more uneven).

I've then looked at Mann Whiney U test since this is distribution agnostic and doesn't matter about differently sized groups. This isn't a test I'm familiar with but I understand you are only really looking here at the median not mean.

Is this right? Does anyone have any suggestions for appropriate tests (ideally using the mean)? Am I right that ANOVA might not be suitable for the reasons outlined?

Comment: ANOVA is fairly robust to the violation of the normality assumption.  I'd start with an anova first.  Maybe a generalized linear model (e.g. gamma regression) may be more suitable but ANOVA would be a good first step.

Comment: In the US, especially in Title VII cases, courts generally have maintained that to raise an inference of discrimination you need to control for relevant variables (to the extent they are available) such as degree of experience.  This is done using a multiple regression.  Re "need groups to be the same size," this isn't so.  Indeed, it is rare that one has the opportunity to determine the sizes of the groups for comparison: in a court case those groups are determined by the scope of the complaint and the statute of limitations (among other things).

Comment: I'm still confused on what you want to do and what type of data you believe you have. Are you merely wanting to determine if there is a difference in pay between men and women or not? What is your hypothetical sample? Does it consist *only* of people who are deemed "comparable in every way except sex" or is your sample more heterogeneous? Are you trying to determine if there is discrimination or not? Are you trying to attribute differences in pay to factors or not? Based on your answers to these questions ANOVA may be out of the question completely.

Comment: Hi @cgmill. I've added a clarification. The situation is what you thought - people who should be the same in every way, so determining if there is a difference between the sexes. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @whuber. I know that groups don't need to be the same size for regression, but I don't think this is a regression problem. See my edit.

Comment: It is definitely a regression problem.  Your reference to ANOVA confirms that (ANOVA is a form of regression).

Comment: Why is it a regression problem? Sorry I don't understand. I just want to compare two groups, not get y in terms of x.